# Uploading file to Mule (http connector) from a HTML page

Tags: html, xml, mule

I am trying to upload an XML file from a HTML page to Mule-3.5 (CE). In Mule, I am unable to retrieve the contents of the file. I am attaching the HTML and the Mule configuration xml. I hope someone could help me through this.

```html
<html>
<body>
<form action="http://localhost:8081" method="post" enctype="text/xml" >
INVOIC IDOC File:<input type="file" name="uploadedFile" size="40"  accept=".xml" />  
  <input type="submit" name="Submit" id="button" value="Send" />

</form>
</body>
</html>
```

```js
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<mule xmlns:json="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/json" xmlns:http="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http" xmlns="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core" xmlns:doc="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/documentation"
xmlns:spring="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" version="CE-3.5.0"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-current.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core/current/mule.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http/current/mule-http.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/json http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/json/current/mule-json.xsd">
<http:connector name="HTTP_HTTPS" enableCookies="true" cookieSpec="netscape" validateConnections="true" sendBufferSize="0" receiveBufferSize="0" receiveBacklog="0" clientSoTimeout="10000" serverSoTimeout="10000" socketSoLinger="0" doc:name="HTTP-HTTPS">
    <reconnect/>
</http:connector>
<flow name="httpconnectorFlow1" doc:name="httpconnectorFlow1">
    <http:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" host="localhost" port="8081" doc:name="HTTP" connector-ref="HTTP_HTTPS"/>
    <echo-component doc:name="Echo"/>
</flow>
</mule>
```

The Mule script is just a test for HTTP connector. I am searching ways to extract the contents of the file uploaded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use this to get things working. The thing that I have changed in the HTML is the enctype and the name of the file input.

```
<html>
<body>
    <form action="http://localhost:8081" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
       INVOIC IDOC File:<input type="file" name="payload" size="40"  accept=".xml" />  
       <input type="submit" name="Submit" id="button" value="Send" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

for the Mule part you can use the HttpMultipartMuleMessageFactory for the HTTP connector. This lets you receive multipart/form data. Since the file input was named payload it will be the payload om the mule message, it will be a streaming payload.

Below is a sample mule flow for receiving the xml in mule and logging the payload. I use a simple object-to-string transformer to read the stream.

```
<http:connector name="HTTP" doc:name="HTTP">
   <service-overrides messageFactory="org.mule.transport.http.HttpMultipartMuleMessageFactory" />
</http:connector>

<flow name="http-xml-receive-flow" doc:name="http-xml-receive-flow">
<http:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" host="localhost" port="8081" doc:name="HTTP"/>
      <object-to-string-transformer doc:name="Object to String"/>
      <logger message="#[message.payload]" doc:name="Logger" level="INFO"/>
</flow>
```

If you plan to include other form inputs they will be available as inboundAttachments on the mule message.